# Send sms using at command

Tags: c#, sms, at-command

AT commands not work. Does anyone know how to do?
I tried this way but phone no actions yet.
port is opened. Select the phone trying to connect to this port. But does not send the message.

```
    private void btngonder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
             try
            {
                if (seriport.IsOpen)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Mesaj Gönderiliyor Lütfen Bekleyiniz");
                    Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                    seriport.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + (Char)13); 
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    seriport.Write(String.Format("AT+CMGS=\"" + txtnumara.Text + "\r\n" + (Char)13));   
                    seriport.Write(String.Format("{0}" + (Char)26 + (Char)13, trDuzelt(txtmesaj.Text)));
                    MessageBox.Show("Mesaj Başarıyla Gönderildi.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Mesaj Gönderilirken Bir Hata Oluştu!", "Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button3);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: (Cahr)13 is `'\r'` so you are sending `"\r\n\r"`, is that what you want?

Comment: And ESCape is 27, not 26

Comment: (Cahr)13 or '\r' not work. message not sent

Comment: It was a question, not an answer.

Comment: I wrote to try. I forgot to delete. For any of you can answer